# Wordpress, wp-fullcalendar (0.8.4) with events manager (5.5.2): how to add additional text to title?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, text, fullcalendar

i'm in the nth hour of trying the following: i'd like to add text/html snippets before the title of an event as displayed in the fullcalendar (i.e. inside of <div class="fc-event-title">). These snippets would be one of the following:

1. <span class="info">registration needed</span>
2. <span class="cancelled">course cancelled</span>
3. <span class="ok">held as planned</span>
4. blank value/no additional text

I tried to copy wp-fullcalendar.php into my theme's directory hoping to be able to edit the function but couldn't accomplish to overwrite the original file - anyplace i tried to put it.

I then tried working in the source file, for a test i did (line 199 in original wp-fullcalendar.php): 
$title = 'LLL' . $post->post_title; which did nothing to the output in the calendar.

After a while i completely removed the function 'function ajax()' from wp-fullcalendar.php and the calendar still displays just fine. Seems to be the wrong place (which it is anyway as it's a source file, i know).

I was hoping to find a quick way to accomplish my task but as you can see i'm stuck.

Any help on the matter would be highly appreciated. Thank you,

Frank

Update:

- i added a custom attribute 'Kurstyp' to each Event.
- possible values for it are: empty string (ie no extra span), 'please register', 'event cancelled', 'held as planned'
- i would like all non empty values to appear within <div class="fc-event-title">
- best each wrapped in a span with an individual class for styling purposes
- this is what i added to wp-fullcalendar.php:

  ```
  add_action('wp_ajax_wpfc_custominfo',array('WP_FullCalendar','custominfo') );
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpfc_custominfo', array('WP_FullCalendar','custominfo') );

  // and further down
  function custominfo() {

      if( !empty($_REQUEST['post_id']) ){
          $return = get_post_meta($_REQUEST['post_id'], 'Kurstyp', true);
      }
      echo apply_filters('wpfc_custominfo', $return);
      die();
  }

  // then, inside the event.render part within fullcalendar_args
  if(event.post_id > 0) {
      alert('event.title (1st): ' + event.title);
      var custominfo = {action: 'wpfc_custominfo', post_id: event.post_id};
      var extra = $.ajax({
          url: WPFC.ajaxurl,
          type: "POST",
          data: custominfo
      });
      extra.done(function(addtxt) {
          event.title = addtxt + event.title;
          alert('event.title (2nd): ' + event.title);
      });
  }
  alert('event.title (3rd): ' + event.title);
  ```

  - addtxt delivers the correct value but my 3rd alert fires before the 2nd one, so event.title remains unchanged
  - all of this takes place in the original source, i'd want to change this even if it worked
  - also, even if it worked: how to style the different messages accordingly?
  - might the attribute className of the Event Object be helpful and if so, how?

The Texts used would be german, tried to use english here for better reading.

Thanks for your help, Frank

Comment: What exactly are you trying to add to the title?

Comment: Updated to hopefully make things clearer.